# Force label to be along the lower perimeter of a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cartography

Some of my grave plot numbers are rendering on the L/R boundaries of polygons rather than being always on the bottom line.

[image]

How can I force this?

These are my Label settings. I have tried the Angle placement as well.
[image]
[image]

I tried the priority and blocking settings but no difference.

I looked at an expression but can't seem to enter any values here. I tried with [ and in ''
[image]

Using QGIS 3.26

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be overkill, and I would certainly be interested in a simpler solution, but nevertheless.

This expression finds the segment of the polygon that has the lowest [Hausdorff Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) from the bottom edge of its bounding box to determine the lower perimeter. The lower segment of the perimeter becomes the *Geometry Generator* placement location for the label. As [Tom Brennan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/129409/tom-brennan) rightly pointed out, the label is rotated parallel to the line by default. And other settings, such as above/below/on line can also be used to refine the label placement.

*Note: `geometries_to_array` is a relatively new function in QGIS. I don't remember exactly which version it was introduced. I am using QGIS 3.34. The function can be emulated in older versions with a couple of extra functions. **-- See bottom of answer --***

*Similarly with the `@geometry` notation. If that causes an error, use `$geometry` instead.*

```sql
with_variable('segments', 
    -- get an array of the segments of the polygon
    geometries_to_array(segments_to_lines(boundary(@geometry))),

    -- make a line of the lower edge of the polygon's bounding box
    with_variable('lower_bound',
        make_line(
            make_point(x_min(@geometry), y_min(@geometry)),
            make_point(x_max(@geometry), y_min(@geometry))
        ),
        
        -- get an array of all segments' hausdorff distance from the lower edge of the bounding box
        with_variable('hd', 
            array_foreach(
                @segments,
                hausdorff_distance(@element, @lower_bound)
            ),
            
            -- use the index of the lowest HD to index the array of polygon segments
            with_variable('bottom_segment',     
                array_get(
                    @segments,
                    array_find(@hd, array_min(@hd))
                ),
    
                -- the lower segment becomes the label location, and as @Tom Brennan pointed out, the label is automatically rotated along the line by default.             
                @bottom_segment
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

###### Settings:

Change to line type for the *Geometry Generator* output.

[image]

Other placement options associated with line labelling are available.

[image]

###### Placement expression for QGIS versions prior to `geometries_to_array` function

```sql
with_variable('segments', 
    -- get an array of the segments of the polygon  
    array_foreach(  
        generate_series(1, num_geometries(segments_to_lines(boundary($geometry)))), 
        geometry_n(segments_to_lines(boundary($geometry)), @element)    
    ),

    -- make a line of the lower edge of the polgyon's bounding box
    with_variable('lower_bound',
        make_line(
            make_point(x_min($geometry), y_min($geometry)),
            make_point(x_max($geometry), y_min($geometry))
        ),
        
        -- get an array of all segments' hausdorff distance from the lower edge of the bounding box
        with_variable('hd', 
            array_foreach(
                @segments,
                hausdorff_distance(@element, @lower_bound)
            ),
            
            -- use the index of the lowest HD to index the array of polygon segments
            with_variable('bottom_segment',     
                array_get(
                    @segments,
                    array_find(@hd, array_min(@hd))
                ),
    
                -- the lower segment becomes the label location, and as @Tom Brennan pointed out, the label is automatically rotated along the line by default.           
                @bottom_segment
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Brilliant. It looks like what we need but I need to get IT to upgrade QGIS for us before testing.

Comment: Is the limitation the `geometries_to_array` function? I can add a modified expression that supports older QGIS versions.

Comment: Yes that function is the issue. If you know of a modified expression, that would be great.

Comment: See the modified expression at the bottom of the answer. It loops through the multiline feature created by the `segments_to_lines` function by generating a series of `1 - the number of geometries` in the multipart geometry.

Comment: That worked for the label. For the rotation I tried to use your replacement but it's not quite right. 
`with_variable('segments', 
    -- get an array of the segments of the polygon  
    array_foreach(  
        generate_series(1, num_geometries(segments_to_lines(boundary($geometry)))), 
        geometry_n(segments_to_lines(boundary($geometry)), @element)    
    ),

         with_variable('hd', 
            array_foreach(`

` rest of your code.

Comment: I added the working rotation expression

Comment: Clever! You could simplify it by just generating the bottom segment (second last step) and using Geometry Generator on the LineString. That way you wouldn't need the rotation as the label would be along a line.

Comment: Good catch! I have updated accordingly. A much more versatile outcome, given the line labeling options.

Comment: This is a genius approach and a very elegant solution, I tried solving this years before and was so stumped. I will definitely be using this in the future!

Comment: Thanks :) I have learnt much from your answers over the years. I haven't tested it on irregular or complex polygons, but, for the case of graves it seems to work well. Probably for buildings or parcels too. The side of the polygon can of course be chosen by generating a different bounds segment (north, east, west). And I suppose it could be extended with rules based on the length or azimuth of the segments.